# Finding exact solutions to a nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've come across the differential equation
$$ 2 x^2 f(x)^2 f^{(3)}(x)+12 x f(x)^2 f''(x)+3 x^2 f'(x)^3-12 x f(x) f'(x)^2+12 f(x)^2 f'(x)-6 x^2 f(x) f'(x) f''(x)=0 $$
and I would like to find the most general exact solution possible.
Plugging in $f(x)=cx^\alpha$, I see that the powers $c,c x^2,cx^{-2}$ are solutions. I couldn't find anything more general than these. Can more general solutions be found for this DE?

Thanks

Comment: The general solution would be the best, otherwise, any solution involving more arbitrary constants would be nice.

Comment: Such ODEs are usually not the beginning, they result from something. Would you mind sharing some context, or at least some thoughts that help identify the background?

Comment: @ccorn I'm not sure about the exact details, but this appears to be  some sort of modification of the simple $(x^2 f^3(x))'''=0$. I hope this helps.

Comment: Maple commands $$ode:=2 x^2 f(x)^2 f^{(3)}(x)+12 x f(x)^2 f''(x)+3 x^2 f'(x)^3-12 x f(x) f'(x)^2+12 f(x)^2 f'(x)-6 x^2 f(x) f'(x) f''(x)=0:  $$  $$infolevel[dsolve]:=5:dsolve(ode)$$ produce the answer $$f \left( x \right) =2\,{\it WeierstrassP} \left( -1/2\,{\frac {\sqrt [
3]{-2\,{\it \_C2}}}{x}}+{\it \_C3},-{\frac {{\it \_C1}\, \left( -2\,{
\it \_C2} \right) ^{2/3}}{{\it \_C2}}},0 \right) {\frac {1}{\sqrt [3]{
-2\,{\it \_C2}}}},
 $$ indicating the use of formal computation of integrating factors.

Comment: @user64494 thank you, that is exactly what I wanted. Please make it into an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maple code 
 $$infolevel[dsolve] := 5:  dsolve(2*x^2*f(x)^2*(diff(f(x), x, x, x))+12*x*f(x)^2*(diff(f(x), x, x))+$$ $$3*x^2*(diff(f(x), x))^3-12*x*f(x)*(diff(f(x), x))^2+
  12*f(x)^2*(diff(f(x), x))-$$ $$6*x^2*f(x)*(diff(f(x), x))*(diff(f(x), x, x)) = 0)$$
  produces
  $$f \left( x \right) =2\,{\it WeierstrassP} \left( -1/2\,{\frac {\sqrt [
3]{-2\,{\it \_C2}}}{x}}+{\it \_C3},-{\frac {{\it \_C1}\, \left( -2\,{
\it \_C2} \right) ^{2/3}}{{\it \_C2}}},0 \right) {\frac {1}{\sqrt [3]{
-2\,{\it \_C2}}}}, $$ indicating the use of computation of integrating factors. See [the pdf file](http://rapidshare.com/files/3823313960/ode.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Just an accompanying comment:

Note that the ODE is such that, whenever $f$ is a solution, then $cf$ will be
a solution as well, for any constant factor $c$.

That $c$ is one parameter of the general solution, and by eliminating it,
the order of the ODE should be reduced by one.

In order to do this, set
$$v(x) = (\ln f)'(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$
Plugging in, I get
$$2x^2 v''(x) + 12x v'(x) + 12 v(x) - x^2 v(x)^3 = 0$$
which should then lead to the Weierstrass $\wp$ solution given by user64494.

Note: The original ODE thus can be written as
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^3}{\mathrm{d}x^3}\left(2x^2\ln f(x)\right) =
x^2 \left((\ln f)'(x)\right)^3$$
which comes close to the hint user1337 has given.

Comment: The Maple command $$dsolve(2*x^2*(diff(v(x), x, x))+12*x*(diff(v(x), x))+12*v(x)-x^2*v(x)^3 = 0)  $$ produces $$v \left( x \right) ={\it \_C2}\,{\it JacobiSN} \left(  \left( {\frac {
-1/2\,i}{x}}+{\it \_C1} \right) {\it \_C2},i \right) {x}^{-2}
 .$$